# Why Jain SipDialog didn't increase localSequenceNumber after it sent reply for Subscribe request?

Tags: sip, jain-sip

I'm using SipUnit to test my sip application which just forward the request. In my simple test case, user1(simulated with SipPhone) send Subscribe request and my application forward the request to user2(simulated
with SipPhone) and then user2 send reply by using JAIN ServerTransaction.sendResponse() method.
Then user2 send Notify to user1 using JAIN SipDialog.sendRequest().
And from the wireshark there is a problem in this Notify request: the CSeq is "1 Notify", but it should be "2 Notify" as it is in the same dialog as the Subscribe so the sequence number should be increased by 1.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

When one party (say A) sends SUBSCRIBE to another (say B), then the NOTIFY will typically come from the B side and each direction, both (A to B) and (B to A) count the requests separately. So SUBSCRIBE will be CSeq 1 from A to B, and the NOTIFY will be CSeq 1 from B to A.